# Sweeby Lax-Wendroff flux

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

I don't quite understand Sweeby's flux limited scheme to solve conservation laws.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} = 0
\end{equation}

In particular, I don't really get **how the expression of the Lax-Wendroff flux is derived and why it depends on the sign on the velocity.**

Looking at the [C.B. Laney book page 473](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU_sf4mfDJAhUThhoKHcO5BZYQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Faerocastle.files.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F10%2Flaney.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEObNxB-AGVAEh6snLLNf3b6dOACA&sig2=eLwC7JtSZKplOhl9p7o0GA), we assume the velocity $a(u)$ is positive and then we have the following lax-wendroff flux :

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}^{LW}_{i+1/2} = f(u_i)+ \frac{1}{2}a_{i+1/2}^n\left(1-\lambda a_{i+1/2}^n\right)\left(u_{i+1}^n - u_{i}^n\right)
\end{equation}

while it says page 474 that if $a(u) <0$ one has :

\begin{equation}
\hat{f}^{LW}_{i+1/2} = f(u_i+1)- \frac{1}{2}a_{i+1/2}^n\left(1+\lambda a_{i+1/2}^n\right)\left(u_{i+1}^n - u_{i}^n\right)
\end{equation}

how are those formulae determined ?

I do understand that the Lax-Wendroff scheme can be written as :

\begin{equation}
u_{i}^{n+1} = u_i^n - \lambda\left(f(u_i)-f(u_{i-1)}\right) - \frac{\lambda}{2}\left(1-a_{i+1/2}^n\right)\left(f(u_{i+1})-f(u_i)\right) + 
\frac{\lambda}{2}\left(1-a_{i-1/2}^n\right)\left(f(u_{i})-f(u_{i-1})\right)\end{equation}

and that this equation can be written

\begin{equation}
u_{i}^{n+1} = u_i^n + C^+_{i+1/2}\left(f(u_{i+1})-f(u_i)\right) -  C^-_{i-1/2}\left(f(u_{i})-f(u_{i-1})\right)
\end{equation}

applying wave splitting, with

\begin{eqnarray}
C^+_{i+1/2} & =&  - \frac{\lambda}{2}a_{i+1/2}\left(1-a_{i+1/2}^n\right)\\
C^-_{i+1/2} & =&   \frac{\lambda}{2}a_{i+1/2}\left(1+a_{i+1/2}^n\right)
\end{eqnarray}

This looks like the formulae for the fluxes are the above equation with either $C^+_{i+1/2}=0$ or $C^-_{i+1/2}=0$, but I don't see why $a(u)>0$ would be equivalent to $C^+_{i+1/2}=0$

Comment: Ok found the misunderstanding... we want the upwind flux to appear in the scheme, and this will depend on the sign of the velocity. Making this appear in the lax-Wendroff formula changes the definition of the flux after little algebra.